# start search from end of range

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, parallel-processing

I'm wondering if it is possible to start a `std::search()` from the end of the range as opposed to the beginning. I know `find_end` would be sufficient, but I would like to specifically know if this is possible with `search`. An example:

I have a data set
`1 2 3 4 5 1 2 | 3 4 5 6 7 1 3` where the `|` represents a break in the range, these two partitions will be executed asynchronously.

Is it possible to search for the range `1 2` starting from the last point in the partition? I would think it would be possible to do some sort of reverse iterator on both the range and the subsequence?

```
search(reverse_iter_begin, reverse_iter_end, reverse_iter_subseq_begin, reverse_iter_subseq_end)
```

Comment: Well, yes, there is a `std::reverse_iterator`.

Comment: thanks for downvoting the question everyone, appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

Standard algorithm `std::find_end` is specially written for containers that have only a forward iterator. For example you can use `std::find_end` with `std::forward_list`

Of course you may use `std::search` with bidirectional iterators either applying iterator adapter `std::reverse_iterator` or uing a built-in reverse iterator of a container as for example the reverse iterator of class std::vector where you can use member functions `rbegin` and `rend`